# Problema ao Debugar

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

Estava usando o emulador do Android para testar meus aplicativos, mas ele é muito lento, passei a usar meu smartphone, mas percebi que muitas vezes o aplicativo não é atualizado. Para resolver eu desinstalo o aplicativo e executo o aplicativo novamente. Teria uma solução melhor para que o Android Studio sempre atualize o aplicativo?

Comment: É suposto, sempre que fizer uma alteração no código, a aplicação ser actualizada no smartphone. Não sei porque isso não acontece consigo.

Comment: tente desabilitar o "instant run"
File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho isso não resolve, também passo por isso no Genymotion, consegui contornar instalando um plugin **ADB unistall**, ao clicar o app é desinstalado, o próximo _run_ pode dar erro, mas executando novamente da certo, é o melhor jeito para evitar de ir no emulador e ficar desinstalado manualmente porque o app não é removido/atualizado corretamente, é chato, mas fazer o que, se a equipe do Android não corrige isso, inclusive já reportei, até agora nada.

Comment: No meu caso, o problema é devido as library's, como estou criando/testando, sempre executo/run com uma nova versão, mas ela não é atualizada, a solução é essa acima, ao menos para mim aliviou o stress de ficar removendo o app manualmente.

Comment: mas se for o caso, jah que nada resolve, vc tambem podem levantar o proprio terminal do android studio e desisntalar via adb: `$ adb uninstall minhaaplicacao.apk`, recursos existem

Comment: @Florida Consigo usar esse plugin ADB Unistall no Android Studio ou só no Eclipse?

Comment: Eu sei que tem para o Android Studio, _talvez_ tenha para o eclipse, recomendo usar o Android Studio, é tudo mais simples com ele.